# Horizontally justify rows of text?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the links in each row div to be justified, and to be centered on the page, so it looks cleaner (assume below is centered on the page):

```
Chrysanthemum.jpg     Desert.jpg     Hydrangeas.jpg
Jellyfish.jpg         Koala.jpg      Lighthouse.jpg
Penguins.jpg          test (1).jpg     test (2).jpg
test (3).jpg          test (4).jpg       Tulips.jpg
```

It doesn't have to look exactly like that, as the image names are of variable length, I'd just like to make it look better than it does now:

html:

```
<div id='image-list'>
        <div class="row">
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg"> Chrysanthemum.jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Desert.jpg"> Desert.jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Hydrangeas.jpg"> Hydrangeas.jpg </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Jellyfish.jpg"> Jellyfish.jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Koala.jpg"> Koala.jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Lighthouse.jpg"> Lighthouse.jpg </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Penguins.jpg"> Penguins.jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/test%20%281%29.jpg"> test (1).jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/test%20%282%29.jpg"> test (2).jpg </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/test%20%283%29.jpg"> test (3).jpg </a>
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/test%20%284%29.jpg"> test (4).jpg </a> 
            <a class="image-link" href="/static/images/Tulips.jpg"> Tulips.jpg </a>                
        </div>            
    </div>
```

css:

```
#image-list{
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

current output, kind of works but puts all my rows on the same "line":
[image]

I've also tried this css:

```
#image-list.row{
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

But that just pushes everything to the left, with no seeming justification:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnUva.jpg)

What am I overlooking or doing wrong?  Do I have to maybe set a div to be a specific width, then justify to that width somehow?

Comment: Can you please create a demo of it?

Comment: @ManojKumar - Give me a second to do that, I'm new to HTML/CSS on SO so will have to see how you set up demos.

Comment: You can make use of Codepen.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are displaying tabular data, so why not use a `<table>`?

If you want some sort of responsive layout, then you can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for desktop, then revert to `display: block` at smaller breakpoints with media queries.

Otherwise, defining a set width for each link will line them up nicely e.g. `.image-link { width: 33.33%; }`

Also, to enable flex items to wrap rather than display on one line, you need to use `#image-list.row { flex-wrap: wrap; }`

Comment: Ah! I needed to step back and realize I should(?) use a table.  That's an excellent suggestion, and makes it much easier to work with.  Thanks so much! (I also added `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` on the `table` in CSS, so it centers on the page.  Thanks again :)